# sz stuck with iTerm2

Tags: macintosh, iterm2

I'm using sz with iTerm2, and sz takes a minute to download a small file (750 byte), I'm not sure why

[image]

Looks like sz is waiting for something?

[image]

Anyone know why?

Besides all that, the contents of the file is printed directly to the screen, that looks weird.

Comment: `sz` might have encountered a control sequence that itsn't properly terminated (such as the Linux color palette).  Also, it *could* be confused by the redirection of I/O done by the `time` command.

Comment: Thanks @ThomasDickey, I tried without `time`, nothing changed (and time is a builtin, no I/O redirection ..). So do you know how to debug it?

Comment: I'd check for the issue with control sequences by capturing the output using `script`.  I forget whether iTerm2 provides a workaround for this case by allowing (your entered) "return" key to terminate the malformed sequences.  It's been a *long* time since I used rz/sz...

Comment: I recommend using iTerm2's download script instead of zmodem. Install shell integration & tools to get `it2dl` or just copy it from here: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gnachman/iTerm2/master/tests/download.sh